# How can my web app retrieve the role(s) of a Facebook User?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK from the web application associated with our Facebook application. I'm in the "Administrator" role for the Facebook application - how do I check for that role from my web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of doing this via the [accounts property on the user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). It gives you an array of pages and apps for which the user has admin privileges.

Unfortunately it will require quite a scary extended permission from September: `manage_pages`.

Try having a play with the new [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Click on the accounts connection (in the right-hand column) for your user.

Answer (score 0):

there's another way:

you can also access the app roles directly via the graph api and you need only the app access token therefore.

https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/roles?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET